# WPF Datatemplating an ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I have an `ItemsControl` whose `ItemsSource` gets bound to an `ObservableCollection<Component>` at run time. I have defined a data template for type `Component` which works fine.

Now `Component` has a `ObservableCollection<Control>` and I want to add another `ItemsControl` inside my `Component` `Datatemplate` to render all the controls. `Control` here is my own custom object not related to a wpf control.

There are different types of controls so I am trying to use an `ItemTemplateSelector` to select the right template for each type. In the example below to keep it small I have only shown one of the templates `"RWString"` which I find using a `FindResource` in `MyControlTemplateSelector` overriding `SelectTemplate`. But the `SelectTemplate` never gets called(using a breakpoint to check). Is there something wrong in my xaml?

```
<ItemsControl.Resources>
    <src:MyControlTemplateSelector x:Key="XSelector" />
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Component}"  >
        <Expander Visibility="{Binding Path=Show}">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Contrls}" 
                          ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource XSelector}">
                <ItemsControl.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate x:Key="RWstring" >
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.Resources>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate><WrapPanel /></ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Expander>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.Resources>
```

**Update:** `Contrls` is not a typo, its just me using a silly naming system. `Contrls` is a property of Component of type `ObservableCollection<Control>`. Also the reason I am trying to use the the `ItemsTemplateSelector` is that the `ObservableCollection<Control>`  contains objects of generic types like `Control<int>` `Control<string>` etc all deriving from `Control` and apparently you cant create datatemplates referring to generic types.

**Update3:** Removed update 2 as it was unrelated. I got the `ItemTemplateSelector` to work by changing `StaticResource` to `DynamicResource`. But I don't know why this works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this doesn't work with a StaticResource as the Resource is inside the ItemsControl which probably has not been created at load time when StaticResources are evaluated.

DynamicResources at load time are evaluated to an expression at load time and then evaluated to the correct value when requested.

Try move the Resource outside of the ItemsControl.

Comment: Thanks that was the problem. I was creating it inside the itemscontrol that was being created at runtime

Answer (score 0):

In the line where you bind the nested ItemsControl, is the Path correct?  It is currently "Contrls", should it be "Controls"?

Comment: It is contrls. I need to change that name though...it is confusing.